# How many Machine Cycles are there in Jump Statements of 8085?

Tags: assembly, 8085

***Which*** Machine Cycles are required for any Jump Statement in 8085 if the condition to be checked satisfies and for the case when it doesn't satisfy?

***EDIT**: I know the number. I want to know what are those Machine Cycles. The first one is Opcode Fetch, but the rest of them?*

Comment: There should be an "instruction manual" explaining this.

Comment: Do you possibly have an 8085?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes sir, I do.

Comment: @sharptooth The instruction manual doesn't explains this.

Answer (score 5):

When the `J condition` is not satisfied, the cycles are

1. `Opcode fetch (4 T states)`
2. `Memory read (3 T states)` of the lower byte specified, while simultaneously checking the flag condition.

If the condition isn't satisfied, the `processor ends` this instruction cycle after these 2 machine cycles and `4+3 = 7 T states.`

Answer (score 3):

According to [this instruction set reference](http://www.phy.davidson.edu/fachome/dmb/py310/EMAC_Primer/8085.InstructionSet.full.pdf), a conditional branch on the 8085 takes 9 T-states (2 M-cycles) if the branch isn't taken, and 18 T-states (5 M-cycles) if the branch is taken.

A T-state equals one clock cycle on the 8085 as far as I know. An M-cycle is made up of several (3 to 6) T-states. Examples of M-cycles are "Opcode Fetch" (which always is the first M-cycle of every instruction); "Memory Read" and "Memory Write".
You can read more about the 8085's states and cycles [in this document](http://www.newagepublishers.com/samplechapter/000495.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

When it does satisfy the condition, the cycles on a 8085A are:

JNZ 9050H

- Opcode Fetch
- Memory Read: to get the lower order address byte
- Memory Read: to get the higher order address byte

4+3+3 = 10 T-States in 3 machine cycles

I got here because I myself am in search of what the cycles are when the condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

If the condition is satisfied 10T states, otherwise 7T states in case of conditional jump.
In case of unconditional jump JMP its always 10T states

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with [Michael's existing answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18630013/224132), which conflicts with yours?  Are they for a different revision of the hardware, or is the manual he found incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take ' JNZ 16-bit address ' instruction as example. 
And following code for understanding :

```
INR B           // B=03 H 
JNZ C200 H
```

Here the condition will be true because register B is not zero. Hence 10 t-states.

If register B =00 H then the JNZ condition will be false as it is zero. Hence 7 t- states.

True: OF + MR + MR = 4 +3+3= 10 t states 
False: OF + MR = 4+3 =7 t states